# Limiting products that can be bought/ added to cart in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, configure

So our store basically sells 6month and annual subscriptions to our businesses website. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that they can only add one subscription (product) to the cart, not multiples, so customers dont make the mistake of buying double subscriptions?

Comment: This question may find a better home over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

**To limit only one item per order**

Create a custom module with a observer to disallow adding items if the cart already has quantity (see getItemsQty()). You should also be aware of updateItem() which could be used to change the quantity of items in one's cart

```
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
checkout_cart_update_item_complete
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
```

See 
 - [Magento - Adding multiple products to cart programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701446/magento-adding-multiple-products-to-cart-programatically)

**To limit one of each product per order**

You can limit the maximum quantity of a product that can be added to your shopping cart by editing the value on the Inventory tab when in product admin.

See [Magento: limit product max quantity to 1 per order. quantity 2 = 2 orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856770/magento-limit-product-max-quantity-to-1-per-order-quantity-2-2-orders)

Comment: I have tried that, but what I want is to limit it to one product per order, not one of each product per order- does that make sense?

Comment: these are deprecated in Magento 2 and don't work on APIs. Use `sales_quote_save_before`